# Where is $ERL_TOP on a macports installation of Erlang

Tags: eclipse, erlang, macports

I've installed Erlang through macports on my macbook and I'm trying to use the [Erlang Eclipse plugin](http://erlide.sourceforge.net/erlide.html#instalation_guide), but it needs me to point it to the **$ERL_TOP** directory.

Where does that exist? I know my erl binary shell is located at:

```
which erl
/opt/local/bin/erl
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a symbolic link in /opt/local/bin/to_erl that brought me to:
/opt/lib/erlang

This appears to be my $ERL_TOP

Answer (score 1):

Mine was slightly different: /opt/local/lib.